# Is it possible to make good fried salmon in a stainless steel pan?

Tags: frying, salmon, stainless-steel

I am trying to make fried salmon in my stainless steel pan. My goal is to have a nicely browned exterior, but I keep running into the same problem: Once the outer layer of the salmon starts to brown, it sticks to the bottom of the pan, and peels right off the fillet when I try to turn the fish over.

The answers to [this](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/18400/how-can-i-stop-fish-from-sticking-to-a-stainless-steel-pan) similar question all seem to be focused on heating the pan before putting the fish in. This doesn't seem to work in my situation. I am already preheating the pan for a couple of minutes. In case it makes a difference, I have been using olive oil.

Is there a special trick to searing salmon in a stainless steel pan (I prefer to avoid pans with non-stick coatings) without the bottom of the fish peeling off as soon as it browns? Am I just doing this entirely wrong?

Comment: @rumtscho All the answers to the linked question seem to focus on preheating the pan. As I state in my question, I am already trying this, but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Your question is not any different from the original one. If there is a different answer, it still should be added to the old question and not to a new one. My best guess is that you just haven't experimented enough to get the temperature correctly (it can take many tries), but even if there were another trick, the proper thing to do is to give a bounty on the old question, not to repeat the same question under the same context and expect a different answer. As I remember how hard it is to give away rep when you have so little of it, I'll put a bounty for you, I have enough to spare.